# Is it possible to get empty line with scanf + regex in c?

Tags: c

I know that `fgets` is more appropriate for this, but would it be possible to use `scanf` to read a line that has only `\n` (maybe by using a regex expression?) ?

EDIT: the formqt suggester by @dasblinkenlight works to get the \n, however, it has undesirable side effects. For example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 char c[80];
 for (int n = 0; n<10; n++){
  scanf("%1[\n]", c);
  printf("%d %s\n", n, c);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

If I just input `enter`, it actually works as expected (catching the new line and printing it). However, if I input another character, it it goes through the loop until the end without waiting for any other input.

Comment: You mean `scanf("<something>", s)` and get `s="\n"` ?

Comment: There's no built-in regex, only something that looks like a very rudimentary regex. A line that has only one `\n` can be read with `%1[\n]` format specifier.

Comment: @EugeneSh. : yeah, the idea is to be able to use it to detect when the user simply presses Enter without adding anything else, but it should also be able to get regular input too.

Comment: @JonathP Then you can just check for an empty string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : what would be the exact syntax? would it still be possible to read other regular input with it too?

Comment: The syntax is regular `scanf` syntax, i.e. `scanf("%1[\n]", buf)` where `buf` is an array of at least two `char`s. It would be possible to read other input before and/or after the `%1[\n]` format.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : ok, but it creates side effects (see edit). Any ideas as to how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `fgets()`.  If the returned string is empty, stop.  If it is not empty, use `sscanf()` to parse it.